# Legacy menu is not showing in android

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, legacy

I am developing an app with actionbarsherlock. Because i need to add compatibility for device under 3.0. In main(first) activity i need to hide actionbar (for design issue). Also that activity has an option menu. Question is how can i add legacy menu for recent version of device which doen't have any hardware menu button. I have checked all the options but not working. I am adding some options here

```
@Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
  {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.layout.coredialer_menu, menu);
    return true;
  }
 #manifest
 <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
```

Comment: You can create custom menu implementation. And this is the only way cause if there is no hardware menu button then the overflow menu must appear or (for older sdk versions) the software menu button will appear at the bottom. You can either develop another design for your first activity which will not use menu at all.

Comment: related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8897763/android-show-menu-button-on-galaxy-nexus Maybe there is a way to don't use Sherlock classes in that activity at all. If so Android must add software menu button automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem by removing **actionbarsherlock**.